# Как сохранить файл в формате xls

Tags: python, pandas, excel

Как создать файл в формате .xls?
У меня на компьютере использую

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.join(path, "File.xls"), engine='xlwt') as writer:
    dataframe.to_excel(writer, index=False)
```

Но когда пробую запустить на сервере выводит ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pandas/io/excel/_util.py", line 91, in get_writer
    return _writers[engine_name]
KeyError: 'xlwt'
```

Comment: Какая версия панды на сервере?

Comment: @Эникейщик версия 2.0.3

Comment: Наверное, надо ещё xlwt установить. https://pypi.org/project/xlwt/

Comment: @Эникейщик xwlt установлен, скорее всего из за версии панды, попробую старую установить

Comment: @Эникейщик понизил версию пандаса помогло! Спасибо!!!